# How to link object files into a raw binary file with gcc/ld?

Tags: assembly, ld, 68000

**UPDATE 2 December 2019:**

I'm having trouble with the m68k-elf toolchain. What I want to do is to translate a simple 68k-assembly file `source.s` like this:

```
    .text 
    move.w %d0,%d1
```

Into an object file, then use a linker script `memmap.ldscript`:

```
MEMORY 
{
    ROM1 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00, LENGTH = 16
    ROM2 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x10, LENGTH = 16
}

SECTIONS 
{
    .text : 
    {
       *(.text)
    } >ROM2
}

OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
```

to link this object file into a raw binary file. The final file should look like this (viewed in a hex editor):

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
30 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

If I build it like this

```
m68k-elf-as -o source.o source.s 
m68k-elf-ld -T memmap.ldscript -o final.rom source.o
```

Then `final.rom` only contains:

```
30 01
```

So the code of the section is placed at 0x00 instead 0x05.

I need "raw" machine code to burn onto a E(E)PROM. But I'd like to use a linker and linker script to be able to assemble sections from several source files into objects files, then link them into one final ROM with the section placement controlled by a linker script. Is this possible with m68k-elf?

Comment: I assume that is equivalent of doing an objcopy step after linking (having that binary line in there).  gnu is going to build the rom file based on the lowest address in the link, so the first byte of the file if you say .text starts at 0x05 will be the byte for address 0x05.  If you want to pad it and make a memory image style binary then you need to put the padding in the assembly .byte 0,0,0,0,0 and make the address 0x00.

Comment: if you link to elf or something like that then you will see your instruction at the right offset with objdump or readelf or whatever, but when you convert to binary it will convert with that lowest address from the link (0x05) as the first byte.  and what I mean by that is if you made .text 0x1000, and .data 0x200 then the objcopy -O binary would have the first byte of the file be the 0x200 byte.  if you did .text 0x100 and .data 0x200 then the first byte 0x100 address and so on.

Comment: Does `ld --oformat=binary` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force the linker to emit the ROM1 region by creating an output section with some content. The [manual says](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Discarding.html):

> Other link script directives that allocate space in an output section will also create the output section. So too will assignments to dot even if the assignment does not create space, except for ‘. = 0’, ‘. = . + 0’, ‘. = sym’, ‘. = . + sym’ and ‘. = ALIGN (. != 0, expr, 1)’ when ‘sym’ is an absolute symbol of value 0 defined in the script. This allows you to force output of an empty section with ‘. = .’.

So this should work:

```
MEMORY 
{
    ROM1 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00, LENGTH = 16
    ROM2 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x10, LENGTH = 16
}

SECTIONS
{
    .dummy :
    {
       . = ORIGIN(ROM1) + LENGTH(ROM1);
    } >ROM1

    .text : 
    {
       *(.text)
       . = ORIGIN(ROM2) + LENGTH(ROM2);
    } >ROM2
}

OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
```

However, at least with my binutils version 2.33.1, it doesn't. `.=.` doesn't work either. If you only need the region for padding, you can emit some data into it, e.g. by a `BYTE(0)` directive and that works:

```
MEMORY 
{
    ROM1 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00, LENGTH = 16
    ROM2 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x10, LENGTH = 16
}

SECTIONS
{
    .dummy :
    {
       BYTE(0);
       . = ORIGIN(ROM1) + LENGTH(ROM1);
    } >ROM1

    .text : 
    {
       *(.text)
       . = ORIGIN(ROM2) + LENGTH(ROM2);
    } >ROM2
}

OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
```

If you do have some content for ROM1 then of course just create input section for it but make sure it always exists otherwise the linker will remove it. Strangely enough, even a zero sized section works.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I gave it a quick check and it works, thanks! I completely misunderstood the dot operator, I assumed it was for symbol assignment only.